# Making a login page with phone number and password on the same default login page

Tags: android, authentication

I am learning and making app for android platform.

I want make login page with phone number and password without registration.

How can I do that? Is there any template? The template of android studio default login activity is very beautiful, but I want login phone number and password. After the login I want intent other activity. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase Authentication for that purpose, because that's pretty straightforward. I'd used that too.

And, you can use [FirebaseUI](https://opensource.google.com/projects/firebaseui). That let you use a pre-built UI for Authentication with a single line of code.

For learning that, this is the link for the documentation :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: This very useful, but i don't want any authentication. Thanks for your answer

Comment: But you asked for phone log-in. and that's what we call authentication

Comment: Well on Stack Overflow, there is no need to thank someone who answers your question. The best way to thanks anyone who answers your question on Stack Overflow is by giving a checkmark on his answer. Checkmark my answer if you found this useful

Comment: i have default authentication with the password, i want make app same the default android studio login activity but without email, with phone number. After the login, i will use phone number in other activity

Comment: You can easily do that thing. Not a big deal if you'll follow the link I've provided to you!